# How to checked all checkbox by javascript and except some checkbox ref by id?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How to checked all checkbox by javascript and except some checkbox ref by id ?

https://jsfiddle.net/o6zwh965/1/

On my code. When press button. All checkbox will checked.

But i want to except not checked checkbox id `111` and id `222`

How to do ?

```
<script>
function js_fn() {
    var all_checkbox_inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = all_checkbox_inputs.length; i < max; i++){
        if (all_checkbox_inputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
            all_checkbox_inputs[i].checked = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the id of the element with an `if` statement

```
<script>
function js_fn() {
    var all_checkbox_inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = all_checkbox_inputs.length; i < max; i++){
        if (all_checkbox_inputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
           {
             if(all_checkbox_inputs[i].id != 111 && all_checkbox_inputs[i].id != 222 )
              {
                 all_checkbox_inputs[i].checked = true;
              }
           }
    }
}
</script>
```